# Does SIP RFC allows multiple endpoints registered to one account?

Tags: sip

Sorry, if this is a repeated question.

I am using FreeSwitch which uses Nokia Sofia SIP stack.
It allows me to register multiple endpoints using one user credentials.
e.g. I can log in using user id 1000 with multiple devices.

I want to know whether SIP RFC 3261 allows multiple endpoints registered to one account or not?

Update me about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RFC 3261 States - 10.2.1 Adding Bindings

Once a client has established bindings at a registrar, it MAY send
   subsequent registrations containing new bindings or modifications to
   existing bindings as necessary.  The 2xx response to the REGISTER
   request will contain, in a Contact header field, a complete list of
   bindings that have been registered for this address-of-record at this
   registrar.

These additional bindings allow users to register as many endpoints to their registration with the REGISTRAR.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about that specific RFC, but most VoIP providers allow to log in with the same account from multiple devices

Answer (score 1):

Yes, RFC 3261 allows multiple endpoints registered to one account.

For instance, you can have three SIP phones, one running at work, one at home, and one on your smartphone.
Then you register all SIP phones using the same account, but with different Contact header addresses.
Each Contact can have a "q" parameter, which indicates a preference level.
So when a call arrives in PBX, it can send the INVITE to the most preferable contact (highest "q" parameter), and if this contact does not answer, the PBX can try the contact with the second highest "q" parameter, and so on.

RFC 3261: 10.2.1.2 Preferences among Contact Addresses
   If more than one Contact is sent in a REGISTER request, the
   registering UA intends to associate all of the URIs in these Contact
   header field values with the address-of-record present in the To
   field.  This list can be prioritized with the "q" parameter in the
   Contact header field.  The "q" parameter indicates a relative
   preference for the particular Contact header field value compared to
   other bindings for this address-of-record.